# Getting a 404 error when using the call log API

Tags: javascript, calllog, ringcentral

I'm using Node and trying to do a simple API call to the call log. My code came from the docs, but modified a bit. Login works just fine so my credentials are ok.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const SDK = require('@ringcentral/sdk').SDK;

RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTID = '<SECRET>';
RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTSECRET = '<SECRET>';
RINGCENTRAL_SERVER = 'https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com';
RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME = '<SECRET>';
RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD = '<SECRET>';
RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION = '101';
var rcsdk = new SDK({
    server: RINGCENTRAL_SERVER,
    clientId: RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTID,
    clientSecret: RINGCENTRAL_CLIENTSECRET
});
const platform = rcsdk.platform();

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {

  await rcLogin();
  let callLog = await rcCallLog();
  console.log(callLog);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(callLog)
    }

}

async function rcLogin() {
  return platform.login({
    username: RINGCENTRAL_USERNAME,
    password: RINGCENTRAL_PASSWORD,
    extension: RINGCENTRAL_EXTENSION
  });
}

async function rcCallLog() {

  return platform.get('/account/~/extension/~/call-log', {
    view: 'Detailed'
  })

}
```

It logs in just fine, but then the callLog call returns `errorMessage: '404 Not Found'`

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out. Changing the call to this worked:

```
return platform.get('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/call-log', {
```

It may just be a bug in the docs for reading the call log (https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/voice/call-log/reading-call-log).